# What is HTML/WHATWG relevant setting object/realm?

Tags: html

In the WHATWG specification I sometimes encounter such terms as object's "relevant setting object" and "relevant realm".

For example, [creating a new browser context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#creating-a-new-browsing-context) algorithm, after a step wherein a new `Document` object was created, contains the following assertion (step 14):

> Assert: document's URL and document's relevant settings object's
> creation URL are about:blank.

Descendant links lead us to some definitions:

> The **relevant Realm** for a platform object is the value of its [[Realm]]
> field. ([link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-relevant-realm))

> Then, the **relevant settings object** for a platform object o is the
> environment settings object of the relevant Realm for o. ([link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#relevant-settings-object))

However, I fail to find the place where `Document` gets a value of its `[[Realm]]` field. In fact, I even do not know where this field is defined for `Document` interface.